# Separation principle in generic models?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

Separation principle 
$\mathbf{Sep}(\mathbf\Sigma^1_n,\mathbf\Delta^1_n)$ 
claims that any two disjoint pointsets of boldface class $\mathbf\Sigma^1_n$ are separated by a $\mathbf\Delta^1_n$ set. 
Separation principle 
$\mathbf{Sep}(\mathbf\Pi^1_n,\mathbf\Delta^1_n)$ 
is understood similarly. 
It is known classically that 
$\mathbf{Sep}(\mathbf\Sigma^1_1,\mathbf\Delta^1_1)$ 
and 
$\mathbf{Sep}(\mathbf\Pi^1_2,\mathbf\Delta^1_2)$ 
hold, while 
$\mathbf{Sep}(\mathbf\Pi^1_1,\mathbf\Delta^1_1)$ 
and 
$\mathbf{Sep}(\mathbf\Sigma^1_2,\mathbf\Delta^1_2)$ 
fail. 
The axiom $V=L$ (anyway, the existence of a good 
$\mathbf\Delta^1_2$ wellordering of the reals) implies that 
$\mathbf{Sep}(\mathbf\Pi^1_n,\mathbf\Delta^1_n)$ 
holds, while 
$\mathbf{Sep}(\mathbf\Sigma^1_n,\mathbf\Delta^1_n)$ 
fails for all $n\ge3$. 
The axiom of projective determinacy $\mathbf{PD}$ implies some other behaviour.
But very little seems to be known about $\mathbf{Sep}$ in various generic models, including such best known ones like adding $\kappa$-many Cohen reals, $\kappa\ge\omega_1$. Basically, afaik this is 1) Harrington's unpublished handwritings of 1974-75, and my own APAL, 2016, 167, 3, 262–283. 
I wonder can someone share some other results in this direction.

*Kanovei, Vladimir; Lyubetsky, Vassily*, [**Counterexamples to countable-section $\varPi_2^1$ uniformization and $\varPi_3^1$ separation**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2015.12.002), Ann. Pure Appl. Logic 167, No. 3, 262-283 (2016) [ZBL06529281](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:06529281) [MR3437647](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3437647)